# How can I delete duplicate emails in Evolution?

Tags: 11.04, evolution, email

How can I delete duplicate emails from Evolution 2.32.2?

Comment: Would you clarify your question?  That is, are you speaking about Evolution's new mail notification in the messaging indicator, or are you suggesting that duplicate emails are displayed within Evolution?

Comment: I have duplicate emails in a folder within Evolution. I would like to delete them.

Comment: Do you get duplicate emails from the same origin (e.g., POP3 mailbox)?

Comment: Hi i have the same problem with evolution.
Is there any plugin available to detect and delete double emails?
I also fetch the emails via pop3 server and use the version Evolution 2.28.3
I only configured one email account.
Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

In 3.2.2, Ctrl-A (select all messages), Message -> Remove Duplicate Messages works for a folder.

Answer (score 4):

That's indeed a very common and annoying problem, especially if you're using POP email.

There used to be a plugin to remove duplicates, however, it stopped working with some version.

Evolution 3.1, which ships with Ubuntu 11.10, now has that functionality integrated (Message ▸ Remove Duplicate Messages). With 2.32 you are forced to upgrade. In addition, the function in 3.1 seems to be neither efficient nor configurable so you might still end up with lots of duplicates that give you something to do on a boring weekend.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can do this (unless there is some kind of POP3 rule you can apply).

You will have to do it manually in your specific version.